# Как записать параметры построчно в регистр расчета в 1С?

Tags: 1с

Изучаю 1С. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - не записываются параметры в табличную часть.

Обхожу табличную часть(тут кусок кода что куда):

```
Процедура ОбработкаПроведения(Отказ, Режим)
    
    // регистр ОсновныеНачисления
    Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Записывать = Истина;
    Для Каждого ТекСтрокаНачисления Из Начисления Цикл
        Движение = Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Добавить();
        Движение.Сторно = Ложь;
        Движение.ВидРасчета = ТекСтрокаНачисления.ВидНачисления;
        Движение.ПериодДействияНачало = ТекСтрокаНачисления.ДатаНачала;
        Движение.ПериодДействияКонец = ТекСтрокаНачисления.ДатаОкончания;
        Движение.ПериодРегистрации = Дата;
        Движение.Сотрудник = ТекСтрокаНачисления.Сотрудник;
        ////Движение.Результат = 0;
        //Движение.Факт = 0;
        //Движение.Размер = ТекСтрокаНачисления.Размер;
        
    КонецЦикла;
    
    Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Записать();
    
    // ОКЛАД
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = 
        "ВЫБРАТЬ
        |   ОсновныеНачисленияДанныеГрафика.Сотрудник КАК Сотрудник,
        |   ЕСТЬNULL(ОсновныеНачисленияДанныеГрафика.ЗначениеЧасыФактическийПериодДействия, 0) КАК ФактЧасы,
        |   ЕСТЬNULL(ОсновныеНачисленияДанныеГрафика.ЗначениеЧасыПериодДействия, 0) КАК ПланЧасы,
        |   ОсновныеНачисленияДанныеГрафика.НомерСтроки КАК НомерСтроки,
        |   ОкладыСотрудниковСрезПоследних.Оклад КАК РазмерОклада
        |ИЗ
        |   РегистрРасчета.ОсновныеНачисления.ДанныеГрафика(
        |           Регистратор = &Ссылка
        |               И ВидРасчета = &Оклад) КАК ОсновныеНачисленияДанныеГрафика
        |       ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ОкладыСотрудников.СрезПоследних КАК ОкладыСотрудниковСрезПоследних
        |       ПО ОсновныеНачисленияДанныеГрафика.Сотрудник = ОкладыСотрудниковСрезПоследних.Сотрудник";
    
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Оклад", ПланыВидовРасчета.ОсновныеНачисления.Оклад);
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка);
    
    РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
    
    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();
    
    Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Записывать = Истина;

    Для каждого СтрДвижение из Движения.ОсновныеНачисления Цикл
        //Если это не оклад, то переходим к следующей итерации
        Если СтрДвижение.ВидРасчета <> ПланыВидовРасчета.ОсновныеНачисления.Оклад ТОГДА
            Продолжить
        КонецЕсли;
        //Встаем в начало выборки
        ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Сбросить();
        //Находим в выборке строчку с номером строки == СтрДвижение.НомерСтроки в поле "НомерСтроки" и получаем ее.
        ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.НайтиСледующий(СтрДвижение.НомерСтроки, "НомерСтроки");
        //Теперь можеи обратиться к полям этой строки и взять резульаты
        //Результат считаем по формуле:
        
        РазмерОкладаСотрудника = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.РазмерОклада;
        Если РазмерОкладаСотрудника = НЕОПРЕДЕЛЕНО  ТОГДА
             Сообщить("Для сотрудника: " + ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Сотрудник + "не установлен оклад!");
             Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Записывать = Ложь;
             Отказ = Истина; 
        ИНАЧЕ
             Движение.Размер = РазмерОкладаСотрудника;
             Сообщить("Сотруднику: " +  ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Сотрудник + " установили оклад:" + РазмерОкладаСотрудника);
             СтрДвижение.Результат = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.ФактЧасы/ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.ПланЧасы * РазмерОкладаСотрудника;
             СтрДвижение.Факт = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.ФактЧасы;
        КонецЕсли;
        Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Записать(, Истина);

    КонецЦикла;
    // Перезапишем изменения в движении документа

    Движения.ОсновныеНачисления.Записать(, Истина);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Вот. меня интересует из этого кода такой момент:

```
Движение.Размер = РазмерОкладаСотрудника;
```

Я же вроде как явно дал знать что надо записать. И даже окно вышло:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если зайти в РЕГИСТРЫ РАСЧЕТА ---> ОСНОВНЫЕ НАЧИСЛЕНИЯ, то видим такую картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. размер записывается только в последнюю строку.

**Собственно сам вопрос:** почему не проходит запись в поле **Размер** для всех строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы пишите в переменную, которая осталась от первого цикла, объявленного вами. Судя по всему, вам надо писать:

```
СтрДвижение.Размер = РазмерОкладаСотрудника;
```